# Angular strictTemplates union types

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, devextreme

I'm using Angular 11 (11.2.14) with DevExtreme UI framework. Typescript version is 4.0.7. I've enabled strictTemplates and now I'm getting this errors on compiling in production:

```
Error: src/app/views/product/product.component.html:11:45 - error TS2322: Type 'string | number | Date' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

11                     <dx-date-box [(value)]="endDate"
                                               ~~~~~~~~
12                                  type="date"
   ~~~~
```

EndDate is defined in Component:

```
endDate: Date;
```

I can't understand the real issue, because DevExtreme types is defined correctly:

```
/**
* An object or a value specifying the date and time currently selected using the date box.
*/
value?: Date | number | string;
```

It seems smth wrong with union types.

Comment: Maybe this is because of two-way binding. It's an equivalent of: `const out: string = (value as Date | number | string)`

Comment: With `strictNullChecks` on, when a value is null or undefined, you will need to test for those values before using methods or properties on that value.

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov, thx, you're correct, it's because of two-way bindings. Is any workaround for this?

Comment: @PsyGik, currently we have no `strictNullChecks` enabled

Answer (score 1):

Cannot add a comment because of not enough reputation... BUT to answer:

> thx, you're correct, it's because of two-way bindings. Is any
> workaround for this?

Yes, of course.

You can create a calculated property (get and set) where the setter accepts all three types and then performs a type-check inside to verify that it is actually a Date type and then set your endDate property in that.